# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$IQ" in

Tags: php

when I use postman agent to pass the data into the database it prompt error in the code but I cant figure out what is the error

insert1.php

```
<?php
    $CN=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $DB=mysqli_select_db($CN,"iostest");
    
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password']
    
    $IQ="insert into scan(name,email,password) values('$name','$email','$password')";
    
    $R=mysql_query($CN,$IQ);
    
    if($R)
    {
        $Message="succeddful"
    }
    else
    {
        $Message="error"
    }
    
    echo($Message);
?>
```

the error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$IQ" in D:\xammp\htdocs\api\insert1.php on line 9**

in this line

```
$IQ="insert into scan(name,email,password) values('$name','$email','$password')";
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated! Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Things to check:

- You are missing multiple semicolons in your code
- You are mixing mysql and mysqli in your code (use mysqli)
- You are wide open to SQL injects

Comment: using all mysqli solved my problems thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolon **;** in line 7, 15, and 19.

Refer below:

```
$password=$_POST['password'];
$Message="succeddful";
$Message="error";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
mysqli_query($CN, $IQ);
```

this will may work